# Is the formula $A\lor (B\land C) = (A \lor B) \land (A \lor C)$ correct?

Tags: logic

I've read the formula written on the title on a mathematics' book and it doesn't seem correct for me:

**For the first part of the formula [A ∨ (B∧C)] I have the following possible values:**

*A; B and C; A and B and C (the Or is not exclusive)*

**For the second part of the formula [(A ∨ B) ∧ (A ∨ C)] I have the following values:**

*A and A (A); A and C; B and A; B and C; ...; A and B and A and C (A and B and C)*

So I can have for the second part of the formula *A and B; A and C* which I can't obtain with the first part of the formula.

If I'm mistaken can somebody please tell me how and give some examples.

thanks,

Bruno

Comment: @Fredrik Meyer ∧ Alex Basson : Thanks you both for your answers ! Unfortunately I can accept only one. Good point for the most comprehensive one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose you have $A \vee (B \wedge C)$.  Then you either have $A$ or $B \wedge C$.  If you have $A$, then you have $A \vee B$ and $A \vee C$.  If, on the other hand, you have $B \wedge C$, then you have both $B$ and $C$, in which case you have both $A \vee B$ and $A \vee C$.  So $A \vee (B \wedge C) \Rightarrow (A \vee B) \wedge (A \vee C)$.

Going in the other direction, suppose you have $(A \vee B) \wedge (A \vee C)$.  So you have both $A \vee B$ and $A \vee C$.  Either you have $A$, or you don't.  If you have $A$, then you have $A \vee (B \wedge C)$.  If, on the other hand, you don't have $A$, then the fact that you *do* have both $A \vee B$ and $A \vee C$ implies that you must have both $B$ and $C$.  Therefore you have $B \wedge C$, and so you have $A \vee (B \wedge C)$, i.e. $(A \vee B) \wedge (A \vee C) \Rightarrow A \vee (B \wedge C)$.

So we've established that $A \vee (B \wedge C) \Rightarrow (A \vee B) \wedge (A \vee C)$ and $(A \vee B) \wedge (A \vee C) \Rightarrow A \vee (B \wedge C)$.  Therefore $A \vee (B \wedge C) = (A \vee B) \wedge (A \vee C)$.

Answer (score 4):

Draw a Venn diagram and think of $A,B,C$ as sets. (consisting of True,False). Then you'll see that the formula is correct.

Or you could draw a truth table.
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Truth_table